# MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers

Tags: python, virtualenv, configparser

I am trying to build collective.simserver according to [this manual](http://plone.org/products/collective.simserver), with some modifications:

```
instead of: virtualenv --python=bin/python2.7 simserver/
I am using: virtualenv --python=myVirtualEnv/bin/python simserver
```

and I managed to come to this point:

```
myVirtualEnv/bin/python bootstrap.py
```

and then it breaks apart with this error info:

```
An internal error occurred due to a bug in either zc.buildout or in a
recipe being used:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/tmpLiHZgo/zc.buildout-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1851, in main
    command)
  File "/tmp/tmpLiHZgo/zc.buildout-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 203, in __init__
    data['buildout'].copy(), override, set()))
  File "/tmp/tmpLiHZgo/zc.buildout-1.6.3-py2.6.egg/zc/buildout/buildout.py", line 1465, in _open
    parser.readfp(fp)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ConfigParser.py", line 305, in readfp
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/ConfigParser.py", line 482, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: /home/nenad/buildout.cfg, line: 4
'<!DOCTYPE html>\n'
Mint-AMD64 nenad #
```

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no section header in the configuration file.

> Essentially, the file consists of sections, each of which contains keys with values.

[Docs ConfigParser python module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 21):

i think im late for answer but it happened for me when i saved Config file as `UTF-8`
Try saving the file as `ANSI`.

Comment: Works with UTF-8 without BOM for python 3.5

Comment: switching from UTF-8 to ANSI solved this for me.

Answer (score 21):

For me, I've seen this error because I mistakenly assume the API of `.read_file()` accepts a file path, but it only accepts a file handle.

Answer (score 9):

This error, is most likely because the sections in the config file are missing a header (or it is incorrectly specified). See the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#module-configparser) docs to see the format the configuration files must have.

A configuration file consists of *sections*, which have to be preceded by a `[header]`, for instance:

```
[DEFAULT]
ServerAliveInterval = 45
Compression = yes
CompressionLevel = 9
ForwardX11 = yes

[bitbucket.org]
User = hg

[topsecret.server.com]
Port = 50022
ForwardX11 = no
```

And each section in the config file will contain key/value pairs separated by a string (`=`  or `:` by default). The *header* of each section has to be in the format `[header]`, anything different will yield a `configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError`.

Comment: In my case, the file has missing one header

Answer (score 5):

Although the question was specifically asked in relation to buildout, this exception can occur more generally if you mistakenly pass a filename instead of a filehandle (or anything else file-like) to `ConfigParser.read_file`

Wrong:

```
config  = ConfigParser()
config.read_file('config.ini')
```

Right:

```
config = ConfigParser()
with open('config.ini') as fh:
    config.read_file(fh)
# or:
config.read('config.ini')
```