# Python3.9.0 Idle Wont Open How Do I Fix This?

Tags: python, pygame, python-idle

I am not sure why my python 3.9 idle isnt opening [VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/08effcc16b03b2fdb609efca5b02ac2d) I have tried multiple times but it still isnt opening for me

I tried repairing it in control panel but it still isnt working
I also tried to reinstall it but I am still having the same problem it just wont open no matter how much I click

my idle path on my folder [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYXyM.png)

```
C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.9
```

on my IDle properties it says V

```
TARGET: C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\pythonw.exe "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\idlelib\idle.pyw"

START: C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\
```

OUTPUT I GET WHEN I PUT `py -m idlelib`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\idlelib\__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import idlelib.pyshell
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\idlelib\pyshell.py", line 49, in <module>
    from idlelib.colorizer import ColorDelegator
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\idlelib\colorizer.py", line 6, in <module>
    from idlelib.config import idleConf
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\idlelib\config.py", line 766, in <module>
    idleConf = IdleConf()
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\idlelib\config.py", line 166, in __init__
    self.LoadCfgFiles()
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\idlelib\config.py", line 758, in LoadCfgFiles
    self.userCfg[key].Load() #same keys
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\idlelib\config.py", line 77, in Load
    self.read(self.file)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 697, in read
    self._read(fp, filename)
  File "C:\Users\Habib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\configparser.py", line 1082, in _read
    raise MissingSectionHeaderError(fpname, lineno, line)
configparser.MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers.
file: 'C:\\Users\\Habib\\.idlerc\\config-main.cfg', line: 1
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python IDLE won´t start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509579/python-idle-won%c2%b4t-start)

Comment: Go through this link. https://youtu.be/DRjTNUOIBIw

Comment: Can you open python itself?  If so, does 'import tkinter' work?  In Command Prompt, does 'python -m idlelib' or 'py -m idlelib' work?  If not, what happens?  Are any error messages displayed.

Comment: I am not sure what u mean by open python but the problem is the idle it just wont open no matter how many times i click it i cant open python

Comment: this is the messahe I am getting back when I put py-m idlelib  I uPDATED the POST

Comment: this is the messahe I am getting back when I put py-m idlelib  I uPDATED the POST

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MissingSectionHeaderError: File contains no section headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13282189/missingsectionheadererror-file-contains-no-section-headers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3.9 is very new and it may not be working with your system try switching back to python 3.8.6 and it looks like you havent added python to path

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I was trying to open (pythonw.exe)
it turns out that I had to open Python\Lib\idlelib\idle.py type(python file(no console))